# Getting a key error while appending lists to dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

I have the following code:

```
import random

dic = {2:[],4:[]}
lis = []

# Create a random dataset of 10 lists
for number in range(0,10):
    # Each list consists of 8 random numbers ...
    lis.append(random.sample(range(0,9),8))
    # ... followed by a 2 or 4, corresponding to dic keys
    lis[-1].append(random.randint(2,4))

# Iterate through lis. Append sublists to dic values, using key per
# last item of sublist, 2 or 4. Strip the key itself.

for i in lis:
    dic[i[-1]].append(i[:-1])    # <----- getting a key error here

# End result should be dic looking like this (shortened):
# dic = {2:[[1,2,5,0,8],[0,4,2,8,3]],4:[[6,2,3,6,2],[2,2,3,1,3]]}
```

As shown in the comment, I am getting a key error when I try to append
the sublist to the value within `dic`. Can’t figure out why. Help?

Comment: What's the problem you want us to fix?

Comment: Also, why are you stripping the 2/4 at the end? That's inconsistent with your prose.

Comment: If you can't explain what you want any better, then show us an example of what you want `lis` and `dic` to look like at the end of the process.

Comment: @MadPhyicist, the 2/4 is already labelled in the dictionary, I want the rest of the list appended. See the edits I made to the question. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to avoid downvotes, read the help files, especially the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [Jon Skeet’s article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) is also a good read.

Comment: @TomZych, the mention of downvotes was a comment, and not part of my question. You literally didn't answer any part of the question.

Comment: I can’t answer the question, because I don’t understand it, or what your code is trying to do. Presumably, the same is true of the other five people who voted to close. All six of us have Python as our top tag, with over 300 upvotes each, so our failure to understand the question is not because we don’t understand Python. I can only suggest, again, that you read the offered resources on how to ask good questions. Please?

Comment: @Tom Zych, thanks for replying, now that is some good criticism. I don't think anyone here is questioning the competency of the people here, I think you are the first person to do so. I will try to break it down per line, and hopefully my question will be better structured.

Comment: Hi Ben, I was not questioning the competency of the people who voted to close, let’s be real clear on that, okay? My point was that six people, all of whom know Python well, could not understand the question you posted. What does that suggest about the question?

Comment: Okay, being unfamiliar with your problem domain, I still don’t understand the rationale behind this code, but I’ve run it with print calls added to show what was going on (a valuable debugging technique I recommend to you), and the problem is in `random.randint(2,4)`. This returns a random integer **between** 2 and 4, including 3. When subsequent code hits a 3, you get a key error. So, use `random.choice((2, 4))` or such. Note that **at no time** did your question state what **problem** you were encountering! This is why you should read the links I posted. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Tom Zych, worked like a charm! Didn't realize that it was producing a 3 in addition to a 2/4. I actually didn't know what the problem was, but it took someone like you to point out my silly mistake. I would mark as answered but I don't see the green checkmark?

Comment: Right, it’s a comment, not an answer. I can’t post an answer because the question is currently closed. I’ve rewritten the title and question the way they should have been written, explaining the **specific problem** in the code. Your question never said what problem you were getting; you were focusing on what you were trying to do with the code. That can be useful, but never let it distract readers from the specific problem. Please, **please**, read the links I posted to avoid such problems in future questions.

Comment: Oh yeah, another good article to read: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being unfamiliar with your problem domain, I don’t understand the rationale behind this code. However, I’ve run it with print calls added to show what was going on (a valuable debugging technique I recommend to you), and the problem is here:

```
lis[-1].append(random.randint(2,4))
```

`randint(2,4)` returns a random integer between 2 and 4, *including 3*. When subsequent code hits a 3, you get a key error. Instead, the line should use something like:

```
lis[-1].append(random.choice((2, 4)))
```